# Printf not working at certain points and unable to figure out formulas

Tags: c

This is a project I have done for school. I have two issues that I has been unable to solve. They occur in the admindistance and distancefunc functions. I can not figure out why the distance is not being properly calculated. This causes the functions to not fully work. The seconds issue is that in the admindistance function it is supposed to print the distance, but this printf statement does not seem to work. Thanks for any help anyone is able to provide.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int generatenum ( int num)
{
    return rand() % num + 1;
}

char admin ( int nrow, int ncolumn)
{
    char bypass;
    printf ( "Anything to tell me?\n");
    scanf ( " %c", &bypass);
    if ( bypass == 'A')
    {
        printf ( "Oh, your an administrator\n");
        printf ( "The random location is %i,%i\n", nrow, ncolumn);
        return bypass;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

float admindistance ( int nrow, int ncolumn)
{
    float grow,gcolumn,distance,rowdifference,columndifference,rowpower,columnpower,oldistance;
    _Bool foundtarget=0;

    printf ( "What is your first guess?");
    scanf ( "%i%i", &grow, &gcolumn);
    rowdifference = nrow - grow;
    rowpower = pow ( rowdifference, 2.0);
    columndifference = ncolumn - gcolumn;
    columnpower = pow ( columndifference, 2.0);
    distance = sqrt ( rowdifference - columndifference);
    printf ( "Distance is %f\n", distance);
    while ( !foundtarget)
    {
        printf ( "What is your next guess?");
        scanf ( "%i%i", &grow, &gcolumn);
        if ( grow >= nrow)
        {
            printf ( "Error: Value entered is outside array size");
        }
        else if ( gcolumn >= ncolumn)
        {
            printf ( "Error: Value entered is outside array size");
        }
        else
        {
            /* CONTINUE */
        }
        rowdifference = nrow - grow;
        rowpower = pow ( rowdifference, 2.0);
        columndifference = ncolumn - gcolumn;
        columnpower = pow ( columndifference, 2.0);
        distance = sqrt ( rowdifference - columndifference);
        printf ( "Distance is %f\n", distance);
        if ( nrow == grow && ncolumn == gcolumn)
        {
            foundtarget = 1;
            printf ( "Congrats you win!");
        }
        else if ( nrow - grow <= 1 && ncolumn - gcolumn <= 1)
        {
            printf ( "YOU ARE ON FIRE!\n");
        }
        else if ( oldistance <= distance)
        {
            printf ( "You are getting colder\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf ( "You are getting hotter\n");
        }
        oldistance = distance;
    }
    return 0;
}

float distancefunc ( int  nrow, int ncolumn)
{
    float grow,gcolumn,distance,rowdifference,columndifference,rowpower,columnpower,oldistance;
    _Bool foundtarget = 0;

    printf ( "What is your first guess?");
    scanf ( "%i%i", &grow, &gcolumn);
    while ( !foundtarget)
    {
        printf ( "What is your next guess?");
        scanf ( "%i%i", &grow, &gcolumn);
        if ( grow >= nrow)
        {
            printf ( "Error: Value entered is outside array size");
        }
        else if ( gcolumn >= ncolumn)
        {
            printf ( "Error: Value entered is outside array size");
        }
        else
        {
            /* CONTINUE */
        }
        rowdifference = nrow - grow;
        rowpower = pow ( rowdifference, 2.0);
        columndifference = ncolumn - gcolumn;
        columnpower = pow ( columndifference, 2.0);
        distance = sqrt ( rowdifference - columndifference);
        if ( nrow == grow && ncolumn == gcolumn)
        {
            foundtarget = 1;
            printf ( "Congrats you win!");
        }
        else if ( nrow - grow <= 1 && ncolumn - gcolumn <= 1)
        {
            printf ( "YOU ARE ON FIRE!");
        }
        else if ( oldistance <= distance)
        {
            printf ( "You are getting colder");
        }
        else
        {
            printf ( "You are getting hotter");
        }
        oldistance = distance;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ( char bypass)
{
    int row, column,nrow,ncolumn,grow,gcolumn,admininput;

    printf ( "Welcome to the Hotter-Colder Game!\n\n");
    printf ( "How many rows and columns are in the grid?\n\n");
    scanf ( "%i%i", &row, &column);
    time_t seconds = time ( NULL);
    int seed = ( unsigned)( seconds);
    srand ( seed);
    int i = 0;
    nrow = generatenum ( row);
    ncolumn = generatenum ( column);
    admin ( nrow, ncolumn);
    if ( admininput == bypass)
    {
        admindistance ( nrow, ncolumn);
    }
    else
    {
        distancefunc ( nrow, ncolumn);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It does not seem to work". You mean it prints nothing?

Comment: yes that was the problem I was having

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the `rowpower` and `columnpower` and then don't use them.

```
rowdifference = nrow - grow;
rowpower = pow(rowdifference,2.0);
columndifference = ncolumn - gcolumn;
columnpower = pow(columndifference,2.0);
distance = sqrt(rowdifference - columndifference);
```

I think the last line should be

```
distance = sqrt(rowpower + columnpower);
```

> The seconds issue is that in the admindistance function it is supposed
>   to print the distance, but this printf statement does not seem to
>   work.

There is nothing wrong with the `printf` statement itself here, so I'm going to assume it is down to the same bug resulting in your distance not being printed.

Comment: Note: `rowdifference = nrow - grow;
rowpower = pow(rowdifference,2.0);
columndifference = ncolumn - gcolumn;
columnpower = pow(columndifference,2.0);
distance = sqrt(rowpower + columnpower);` simplies to `distance = hypot(nrow - grow, ncolumn - gcolumn);`